How can I make a ggplot2 graph with the colors set to a gradient except that I want the values to be log transformed?
I'm making a ggplot2 graph in which I've mapped an extremely wide range of numbers to the color. The problem is that my numbers are log-normally distributed, so I have a bunch of numbers all getting set to the same color since the gradient in ggplot2 assumes that the values are on a pretty similar linear scale. Here are some example data:
DF <- data.frame(A = 1:10, 
             B = 1:10, 
             C = 10^seq(-5, 4))

When I use the regular ggplot2 settings, all but my very last point are dark blue.
ggplot(DF, aes(x = A, y = B, color = C)) +
   geom_point()


If I log transform these values, the colors look better, but now my legend shows log-transformed values rather than the actual values.
ggplot(DF, aes(x = A, y = B, color = log10(C))) +
   geom_point()


I also tried using scale_color_gradientn in hopes that maybe I could set the numerical breaks the way I wanted, but that really did not work. The extremely small values are now all grey or missing.
ggplot(DF, aes(x = A, y = B, color = C)) +
   geom_point() +
   scale_color_gradientn(colors = grDevices::blues9, 
                         values = 10^seq(-5, 4))


Is there a way to make the colors of my gradient be on a log10 scale but the labels still be the actual values?

scale_color_gradient2, for case, has a "transform" parameter you can set for an apropiate function

You were almost there, you need to specify the color range:
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 1:10, C = 10^seq(-5, 4))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = A, y = B, color = C)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +  
  scale_color_gradient(trans = 'log10',  
                       low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue",, 
                       breaks = 10^seq(-5, 4),  
                       labels = scales::comma) +  
  labs(color = "C Value") +  
  theme_minimal()  

which gives

If you still think the light blue colors are too greyish (light blue contains grey, I would advise you to change to other colors:
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 1:10, C = 10^seq(-5, 4))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = A, y = B, color = C)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +  
  scale_color_gradient(trans = 'log10',  
                       low = "blue", high = "red", 
                       breaks = 10^seq(-5, 4),  
                       labels = scales::comma) +  
  labs(color = "C Value") +  
  theme_minimal()  




Perfect! Yeah, I'm actually using a different set of colors than the blues in my actual graph, but this worked perfectly even when I specified those colors with scale_color_gradientn. Thanks!
